# How to integrate ledger wallet in REACT DAPP?

Tags: erc-20, ico, ethereumjs, ledger-nano-s

i cant seem to find a way to integrate ledger wallet in react DAPP. Like which library to use. Any kind of guidance and starting material would be helpful.
Thank You

Comment: In order to integrate ledger wallet all you have to do is use ledger hq library and use infura provider and through ledgerhq you can easily work around with the integration